# Build data structure to perform reverse and report queries in poly-logn time

Tags: algorithm

> Given a sequence of *n* numbers, {*a*<sub>1</sub>, *a*<sub>2</sub>, *a*<sub>3</sub>, …, *a*<sub>*n*</sub>}. Build a data structure such that the following operations can be performed in poly-logn time.
>
> 1. Reverse(*i*, *j*):
>
>    > Reverse all the elements in the range *i* to *j*, as shown below:
>    >     Original Sequence: <… *a*<sub>*i*-1</sub>, *a*<sub>*i*</sub>, *a*<sub>*i*+1</sub>, …, *a*<sub>*j*-1</sub>, *a*<sub>*j*</sub>, *a*<sub>*j*+1</sub>, …>
>    >     Sequence after swap: <… *a*<sub>*i*-1</sub>, *a*<sub>*j*</sub>, *a*<sub>*j*-1</sub>, …, *a*<sub>*i*-1</sub>, *a*<sub>*i*</sub>, *a*<sub>*j*+1</sub>, …>
> 2. Report(*i*):
>
>    > Report the *i*-th element in the sequence, i.e. *a*<sub>*i*</sub>.
>
> Here, poly-logn means some power of log *n*. like log(*n*) · log(*n*) may be acceptable.

[*Note: Thanks to Prof. Baswana for asking this question.*]

Comment: Is this a homework question?  It's an awesome question, but if it's for a class you really should let us know and describe what you've tried so far.

Comment: @templatetypedef: It is not homework question.The question was asked by Prof. Baswana(thanks to him) for motivated students in previous semester,and it's perfectly fine to discuss here.

Comment: note: `polylog(n) ~~ log(n)**k for some k`.

Comment: Putting all elements in height-balanced binary tree. Augumenting a field called RANK,i.e RANK(v)=no. of children of tree rooted at v + 1, when reverse(i,j) query is performed,the nodes from i,j along the path to root are marked as 'reversed'. Any way,I am on the way to answer,which is yet incomplete.

Comment: Wouldn't a skip-list work for this?

Comment: Use an implicit treap (also called implicit Cartesian tree). Google for code.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking of using a binary tree, with a node augmented with a *Left|Right* indicator and the number of elements in this sub-tree.

- If the indicator is set to `Left` then begin by reading the left child, then read the right one
- Else (set to `Right`) then begin by reading the right child, then read the left one

The `Report` is fairly obvious: `O(log n)`

The `Revert` is slightly more complicated, and I am unsure if it'd really work.

The idea would be to "isolate" the sequence of elements to reverse in a particular sub-tree (the lowest possible). This subtree contains range `[a..b]` including `[i..j]`

- Reverse the minimum sub-tree that contains this sequence (change of the indicator)
- Apply the `Revert` operation to `[a..i-1]` and `[j+1..b]`

Not sure it really works though :/

**EDIT**:

The previous solution does not work :) I can't imagine a solution that does not rearrange the tree, and they do not respect the complexity requirements.

I'll leave this there in case it gives some idea to someone else, and I'll delete it afterward unless I find a solution myself.

Comment: There are ranges that aren't completely under the same single root... like if you have 8 nodes.. then 3-6 will be a range that half of it is on 1 side, and another is on the other

Comment: @Yochai: there is always a common root though, that is the starting point for the transformation.

Comment: Sure there is a common root, what im saying is that although they have a common root node, you can't save the "flipping" information there, because half of the nodes are on 1 side of the tree, and half on the other. For my example, if you flipped 3-6 , then 1-2 and 7-8 are in regular order, but the only common root to 3-6 is the root node.

Comment: @Yochai: ah yes, as I said I wasn't sure it worked, and with a full belly I've came to realize it didn't. It really is an interesting little enigma, there is no data-structure I know of (sufficiently) that seems to be adaptable to cover this :D

Answer (score 0):

Splay trees + your decorations get O(log n) amortized. The structural problems Matthieu encountered are dealt with by the fact that in O(log n) amortized time, we can change the root to any node we like.

(Note: this data structure is an important piece of local search algorithms for the Traveling Salesman Problem, where people have found that two- and three-level trees with high arity are more efficient in practice.)